# Analytical solution to complex Heat Equation with Neumann boundary conditions and lateral heat loss

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have solved a PDE in this from numerically on *Mathematica*, but does anyone know if there is a way to solve the following PDE analytically, an analytical solution would really help me. This is an adapted heat equation accounting for lateral heat loss in a rod of length $0.2$ ${m}$:

$$u_{t} =\alpha u_{xx}-\kappa(u-T_{0})$$

Where:

$\alpha=1.12*10^{-4}$$m^2 s^{-1}$

$\kappa=2.61*10^{-4}$$s^{-1}$

$T_{0}=17$ C

With boundary conditions:

$$u_{x}(0,t) =0$$ 
$$u_{x}(0.2,t) =0$$

And initial condition:

$$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{59.9842x},0<x<0.1 \\
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{59.9842 (-x + 0.2)},0.1<x< 0.2 \\
\end{cases} $$

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Taking $w(x,t)=(u(x,t)-T_0) \, e^{\kappa t}$ as your new unknown function will bring you back to the ordinary heat equation, which has a standard solution in terms of Fourer cosine series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $\{ \cos(n\pi x/L) \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ form a commplete orthogonal set of functions on $[0,L]$. So you can expand
$$
              u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(t)\cos(n\pi x/L).
$$
In order to solve the equation, plug this form into the equation and solve for the coefficient functions $c_{n}(t)$:
$$
             \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\{c_{n}'(t)+\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}c_{n}(t)+\kappa c_{n}(t)\}\cos(n\pi x/L)= \kappa T_{0}
$$
The right side is a series in the $\cos$ terms where only the coefficient of the constant term is non-zero. Therefore,
\begin{align}
                c_{0}'(t)+\kappa c_{0}(t) & =\kappa T_{0},\\
                c_{n}'(t)+(\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}+\kappa)c_{n}(t) & =0,\;\; n > 0.
\end{align}
The solutions of these equations involve an initial constant $c_{n}(0)=C_{n}$. For $n=0$:
$$
              (e^{\kappa t}c_{0}(t))'=(e^{\kappa t} T_{0})' \\
               e^{\kappa t}c_{0}(t)-C_{0} = T_{0}(e^{\kappa t}-1) \\
            c_{0}(t) = C_{0}e^{-\kappa t}+ T_{0}(1-e^{-\kappa t}).
$$
For $n > 0$,
$$
               c_{n}(t) = C_{n}e^{-(\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}+\kappa)t}
$$
The last condition to be satisfied is the initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, which becomes
$$
            f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L).
$$
Hence, using the orthogonality of the $\cos$ terms,
$$
              \int_{0}^{L}f(x)\cos(m\pi x/L)dx = C_{m}\int_{0}^{L}\cos^{2}(m\pi x/L)dx.
$$
Note that $\int_{0}^{L}\cos^{2}(m\pi x/L)dx=L/2$ for $m \ge 1$ and $L$ for $m=0$.
The final solution:
$$
   u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\cos(n\pi x/L)dx\right)
             e^{-(\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}+\kappa)t}\cos(n\pi x/L) \\
        + \left(\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)dx\right)e^{-\kappa t}+ T_{0}(1-e^{-\kappa t}).
$$
Check everything. I'm good at errors. :)

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your help. I have 2 questions, why in the first step did you assume that u(x,t)=∑n=0∞cn(t)cos(nπx/L)? Also do you need a cosine term in c′n(t)+(αn2π2/L2+κ),=0 n>0. Also can any piecewise continuous function on the interval [0,L] be expanded as a Fourier cosine series? When I tried to do so for my function it kept over estimating it. But thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I used $\cos(n\pi x/L)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ because these are the eigenfunctions of $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ for which $f'(0)=f'(L)=0$. Automatically, when normalized to have integral $1$ on $[0,L]$, they become a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,L]$, which means everything can be expanded in these functions; and the expansions converge pointwise under standard conditions, except possibly at the endpoints $0$, $L$ because of endpoint conditions. Your function $f$ needs to satisfy $f'(0)=f'(L)=0$ for more uniform convergence, and this is a consistency requirement for your problem, too.

Comment: @DanielManogaran : I forgot to you ping you on the previous remark. Knowing that you can expand every function in this way, you can verify directly that the solution I've given you is correct. However, check the normalization constants for yourself: $\int_{0}^{L}\cos^{2}(n\pi x/L)dx$, but definitely notice that the one for $n=0$ is different from the others. Note: when you have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)$ for a.e. $x\in[0,L]$, then $c_n=d_n$.

Comment: @DanielManogaran : I found an error. When I integrated the $c_0$ equation, the $\kappa$ multiplier on the right side should have disappeared. I'm fixing that.

Comment: Great solution, well explained, (+1).

Comment: @TrailAndError I added some more information specific to this problem. Will it still be possible to solve the problem with the initial condition even though the derivatives are not zero?

Comment: @DanielManogaran : Yes, that will still work. It's just that at $t=0$, you won't have $u_{x}=0$ at the endpoints because $u(x,0)$ doesn't satisfy that condition. After $t > 0$ you would still have $u_{x}=0$ at the endpoints, which is a standard insulated strip. You just have a bunch of integrals to perform (really just one because the $\cos$ terms have the same basic form.) The nice thing about the heat equation is that you don't need many terms for $t$ of any significant size because of the $n^{2}$ in the exponent of the time term.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Just one more question, I am still confused at the step when you say $c_{n}'(t)+(\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}+\kappa)c_{n}(t) &=0$, what exactly did you do here? I don't understand why the LHS is zero and what happened to the Cosine. Im sorry I am not that familiar with a PDE like this.

Comment: @DanielManogaran : Substitute $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(t)\cos(n\pi x/L)$ into $u_{t}-\alpha u_{xx}+\kappa u = \kappa T_{0}$. Note that $u_{t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}'(t)\cos(n\pi x/L)$, and $-u_{xx}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(t)\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\cos(n\pi x/L)$, etc. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\{ c_{n}'(t)+\alpha \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}c_{n}(t)+\kappa c_{n}(t)\}\cos(n\pi x/L)=\kappa T_{0} = \kappa T_{0}\cos(0x)+0\cos(\pi x/L)+0\cos(2\pi x/L)+\cdots$. If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)$, then $r_{n}=s_{n}$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Ohh ok so that is why $c_{n}'(t)+(\alpha n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}+\kappa)c_{n}(t) & =0,\;\; n > 0$ Thanks, is there a name or a proof for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L)$? Thank you very much,  you really helped me.

Comment: @DanielManogaran : You're welcome. Because $\kappa T_{0} = \kappa T_{0}\cos(0^{2}\pi^{2}x/L^{2})+0\cos(1^{2}\pi^{2}x/L^{2})+0\cos(2^{2}\pi^{2}x/L^{2})+0\cos(3^{2}\pi^{2}x/L)+\cdots$. So the coefficient of $\cos(n\pi x/L)$ is $\kappa T_{0}$ for $n=0$ and is $0$ otherwise. That must match the series on the left, term by term; remember that you have an orthogonal basis, which means there's only one way to expand. This is part of Hilbert space theory, but it's also just classical orthogonal Fourier expansion.

Comment: @DanielManogaran : The elegant part for me is that the eigenfunctions of the operator $Lf=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f$ on $[a,b]$ that satisfy fixed conditions $Af(a)+Bf'(a)=0$ and $Cf(b)+Df'(b)=0$ where not both $A,B$ are $0$ and not both $C,D$ are $0$ is always a complete orthogonal basis!! That's a non-trivial fact that extends to a broad class of eigenvalue problems $Lf=-\frac{d}{dx}p\frac{d}{dx}f + qf = \lambda w f$ ... basically every non-singular problem arising from separation of variables. You can  choose your basis to turn some differential operation into multiplication by eigenvalues.